# Change StyleSheet of QToolBox in Qt

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I am designing a `GUI` in `Qt`. I have a `MainWindow` and a `QToolBox` in it. The class of my `MainWindow` is `QTabWidget`.

According to the following pictures, I have a `QToolBox` with two tab named `Encoder` and `Decoder`.
[image]

I could change the background color of each `tab` and its `border`.

But I don't know how to change the color of background of each `pane/tab`.

For example I want to change the color of `Decoder` pane to blue as follow.
[image]

It is possible to put a `frame-widget` to page and change its background.

But is it possible to change the `stylesheet` of `QToolBox` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this stylesheet to access certain pages in `QToolBox`:

```
QWidget#page,
QWidget#page_2,
{
  background: blue
}
```

Where `page` and `page_2` are object names of your pages. You can find them in QtDesigner - `currentItemName`.

Or use this stylesheet to apply changes to all pages:

```
QToolBox QScrollArea>QWidget>QWidget
{
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
QToolBox tb;
tb.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue");
```

If that won't do for you, there is a good list of examples on [Qt Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html). Maybe you can find what you want from here.

Comment: No, That does not work. There is two example in [Qt Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) which you can change color of each tab. I did this work as you see in above pictures `Encoder` and `Decoder` tabs. But I want to change the color of inside.