# Change color of certain tab of QToolBox

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I want to change a color of certain tab (page) of `QToolBox` like this

[image]

I figured out how to change a style of every tabs independently like this (StyleSheet):

```
        QToolBox::tab {
            background: blue;
            border-radius: 5px;
            color: black;
        }
```

Also I know how to change a palette of each `QWidget` (via [`setPalette`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#palette-prop) or StyleSheet like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567624/change-stylesheet-of-qtoolbox-in-qt)). But it changes only body of certain tab, it doesn't affect the head of tab.

So, I can not figure out how to change a certain tab. Probably there is some [`paintEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#paintEvent) or [`tabletEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#tabletEvent) but I still don't understand how to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with creating my tool box widget. I didn't play with palette, but I think you can change it easy. Also there is capability to expand several pages at the same time.

```
class MyToolBoxWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.vertical_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.vertical_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vertical_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.pages = []
        self.tabs = []

        self._first_v_spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

    def addItem(self, page, name, color=None):
        tab_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(name)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        tab_button.setFont(font)
        page.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding))
        page.hide()
        self.pages.append(page)
        self.tabs.append(tab_button)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(tab_button)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(page)
        tab_button.clicked.connect(self._button_clicked)

        if color:
            self.setColor( (len(self.pages) - 1), color  )

    def setColor(self, index, color):
        palette = self.get_palette(color)
        self.pages[index].setPalette(palette)
        self.tabs[index].setPalette(palette)
        self.pages[index].setAutoFillBackground(True)

    def check_if_all_pages_are_hidden(self):
        areHidden = True
        for page in self.pages:
            if not page.isHidden():
                areHidden = False
                break
        if areHidden:
            self.vertical_layout.addItem(self._first_v_spacerItem)
        else:
            self.vertical_layout.removeItem(self._first_v_spacerItem)

    def _button_clicked(self):
        i = self.tabs.index(self.sender())
        if self.pages[i].isHidden():
            self.pages[i].show()
        else:
            self.pages[i].hide()
        self.check_if_all_pages_are_hidden()

    def get_palette(self, color):
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(42, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Light, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Midlight, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Dark, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Mid, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(42, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.BrightText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(42, 85, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Shadow, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipBase, brush)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ToolTipText, brush)

        return palette
```

Usage in the main app:

```
my_tool_box = MyToolBoxWidget()

page1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
my_tool_box.addItem(page=page1, name="Tab 1", color="#4ade00")

page2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
my_tool_box.addItem(page=page2, name="Tab 2", color="#009deb")

page3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
my_tool_box.addItem(page=page3, name="Tab 3", color="#f95300")

# Add spacer in the end
my_tool_box.check_if_all_pages_are_hidden()
```

Answer (score 2):

I took the answer from here:
https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/2916-QToolBox-Colors

Translating this to python I came to the following solution:

```py
btns = self.toolBox.findChildren(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton)
btns = [btn for btn in btns if btn.metaObject().className() == "QToolBoxButton"]
for i, btn in enumerate(btns):
    # here you can check e.g. for i
    color = QtCore.Qt.red      # or any other
    p = btn.palette()
    p.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Button, color)
    btn.setPalette(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Qt Style Sheets Examples
>
> ### http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtoolbox.html

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        toolbox = QToolBox()
        layout.addWidget(toolbox, 0, 0)

        label1 = QLabel("Example content, Tab 1")
        toolbox.addItem(label1, "Tab 1")

        label2 = QLabel("Tab 2 ....", styleSheet="""
            background-color: red;
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
            color:white;
        """)
        toolbox.addItem(label2, "Tab 2")

        label3 = QLabel("""
        <b>QToolBox::tab:last </b>{<br>
            background: #f95300;<br>
            border-radius: 5px;<br>
            color: black;
        }
        """)

        toolbox.addItem(label3, "Tab 3")


# StyleSheet
StyleSheet = """

Window{background: #b8cdee;}

QToolBox::tab {
    background: #009deb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
}

QToolBox::tab:first {
    background: #4ade00;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
}

QToolBox::tab:last {
    background: #f95300;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
}

QToolBox::tab:selected { /* italicize selected tabs */
    font: italic;
    color: white;
}
"""

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet) 
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: and if they were more than 3 elements, for example 10, and each one with 10 different colors, how would it be done?

Comment: how would you address tabs in the middle? Can you use "second" "third" etc.?